# HDD is preventing ubuntu from installing

Tags: linux, hard-drive, formatting, ext4, superblock

I have recently attempted to install `ubuntu` on my laptop, replacing windows 7.

The `HDD` was working fine with windows 7.

On my first attempt to install ubuntu it kept giving me an error that was saying it could not create the partitions needed for the installation.

I then tried to manually delete all the partitions that were on the `HDD` and then attempt the installation. Then it started saying that it could not create the `ext4` file system.

So, then i tried deleting partitions again and found out that i had a bad `superblock`. So, then i tried the suggestions in this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/). This did not solve the superblock problem.

So, then i used `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda` to try and just format the whole drive. Everything seemed fine, and then the installation failed. It said it was unable to create the partitions again.

I am on the live cd and gparted does not detect any `HDD` any more.

I need to get ubuntu installed on this HDD. Can someone please assist me in getting this HDD to work again.

Let me know if you need any further details. Thanks!

---

Output from `sudo fdisk -l`:

`fdisk: unable to read /dev/sdc: Input/output error`

Comment: You said gparted does not detect you HD no more, have tried checking your bios to see if it's detected at boot time? if its not detected at boot time, make sure you HDD is attached properly also. ...

Comment: As WeloSefer said.. If you do get past this part, if i recall, when you come to partition the drive during the install process there's a tick box to force a proper format of the partition.  However if your machine cant detect the drive, it may be damaged.

Comment: Bios sees the HDD. I do not believe the drive is physically damaged. I just think that i have formatted the drive incorrectly. How can i format the drive so that it will be ready accept an ubuntu installation with an ext4 file system?

Comment: @prolink007 try disabling `SATA native support` from bios and try booting from gparted. If that doesn't work then can you include the output of `fdisk -l` with your question ?

Comment: @WeloSefer: How do i disable SATA native support? All i see is `SATA Mode: AHCI Mode` and the second option for this field is `IDE Mode`. Everything else in the bios is `security and boot`.

Comment: @prolink007 Try switching from one to other to see if it helps... If you could find a way to include the output of `fdisk -l` it will be great

Comment: Added output from `fdisk -l` in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

@prolink007 I did some reading regarding your problem and I found out that left over GPT data on the hard drive confuses GParted. SO, in order to fix the issue you have to use `GPT fdisk aka gdisk` try the following steps which might help.

```
 1. Boot into Gparted and go to counsel    

 2. Type "gdisk /dev/sda" (change "/dev/sda" to whatever is appropriate to access your hard disk,
     if necessary). you can use gdisk -l to print out the info needed

 3. The program is likely to complain that it's found both MBR and GPT data, and will ask which 
    to use. It doesn't matter which you tell it to use.

 4. At the "Command" prompt, type "x" to enter the experts' menu.

 5. At the "Expert command" prompt, type "z" to "zap" (destroy) the GPT data.

 6. Type "y" in response to the confirmation about destroying the GPT.

 7. Type "n" in response to the query about blanking the MBR.
```

Hope this fix the issue. Let me now

Comment: I got the live cd of `gparted` from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/old-gparted-livecd/gparted-livecd-0.3.4-11/gparted-livecd-0.3.4-11.iso/download. I booted into the default selection and it is now saying a long error. The important stuff seems to be: `Write protect is off` and `Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA`. And it just says a lot of that on the screen. It did not bring me to a desktop or command prompt.

Comment: That's odd. Try resting your bios to default setting and try again. If that doesn't work, you HD is done. It might have some physical damage ie if you have dropped your laptop recently. =\

Comment: Never dropped it. It just started acting like this after i attempted to install ubuntu. I might try to put windows back on to see what happens. I will try your bios suggestion and the windows thing and let you know what happens. Thanks

Comment: The windows installation does not see my `hdd` either.

Comment: Now my bios is not seeing the `hdd`! Is there a way that i need to mount the drive or something?

Comment: No, the bios was suppose to pick it up if the hard drive is plugged in. The mounting part is OS job. Maybe the hdd is not sitting right in its fixed position... remove and dust the area and plug it back in. and try again... if that doesn't work, its most likely ur hdd is out service. =\

Comment: @prolink007 did you fix your problem ?

Comment: Not yet, i was waiting to see if any others had suggestions and i was probably going to buy a new internal hdd for my laptop to see if that fixes it.